# Trim the first digit of a Phone number to be in International format

Tags: php, regex, validation, phone-number

Am working on a web application whereby am capturing phone number from the user, but on the backend (build in Laravel PHP) I want to **trim the first digit from the phone number and replace it with 254**.

For instance,, am capturing this phone number `07******23**`
I need to replace the first zero with `254` so that it can be `2547******23**`

Comment: what if the 1st digit is not `0`? Even then you want to replace? Moreover, what have u tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to invoke regex here, `substr()` should work just fine:

```
$input = "07123456789";
$output = "254" . substr($input, 1);
```

If you only want to do this replacement on numbers beginning with zero, then it might make more sense to use `preg_replace`:

```
$output = preg_replace("/^0/", "254", $input);
```

Comment: Substr will only work if you know for sure the user inputs the zero

Comment: @Andreas It isn't clear whether this is an actual requirement.  In any case, I offered a regex option should that be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Use ltrim to remove the zero.
It will remove the zero if it's there, and leave the string intact if not.

```
echo "254" . ltrim($number, "0");
```

See example with and without the leading zero:
https://3v4l.org/Z03st

Comment: This assumes the OP only wants to replace a leading zero, and not some other digit.

Comment: That is what the question is, isn't it?